# How use a single instance of a class for all request RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have class Named as PriorityJobScheduler and in RestControll i want create its object only once to for all the request for that I am instanciating this class in @PostConstruct method but for each new request i am getting a new object.

I want know how can i instanciate this class only once and use its object for all requests.

```
public class PriorityJobScheduler {
 Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PriorityJobScheduler.class);

 private ExecutorService priorityJobPoolExecutor;
 private ExecutorService priorityJobScheduler = 
                Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
 private PriorityBlockingQueue<DowloadProccess> priorityQueue;

 public PriorityJobScheduler(Integer poolSize, Integer queueSize) {
    Comparator<DowloadProccess> priorityComparator = Comparator.comparingInt(DowloadProccess::getJobPriority).reversed();
    
    priorityJobPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
    priorityQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<DowloadProccess>(queueSize, priorityComparator);
    priorityJobScheduler.execute(() -> {
        while (true) {
            try {
                log.debug(priorityQueue.take().toString());
                priorityJobPoolExecutor.execute(priorityQueue.take());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}


   public void scheduleJob(DowloadProccess job) {   
       priorityQueue.add(job);   
       log.debug("Jobs in queu :: " +  priorityQueue.size());   
   }
```

}

My controller

```
@RestController
   public class ZcrController {
    private static int POOL_SIZE = 1;
    private static int QUEUE_SIZE = 100;
    PriorityJobScheduler pjs;
    
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
         pjs = new PriorityJobScheduler(POOL_SIZE, QUEUE_SIZE);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/zcr/run")
    public List<Map<String,Object>>  exicuteCRTask(@RequestParam(required = false) String agentId,@RequestParam(required = false) String callCenterId,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String clientId,@RequestParam(required = false) String skillId,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String interval,@RequestParam("callRecordingId") String callRecordingId,@RequestParam(required = false) String type, @RequestParam(required = false) String customReport,@RequestParam(required = false) boolean ivrAcd,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String endDate, @RequestParam(required = false) String startDate,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String startTime, @RequestParam(required = false) String endTime) {
        ITxn txn = new TxnToken();
        List<Map<String,Object>> listCDRDetail = dao.getIvrRecords(txn, params,dbParam,type);
        log.debug("CDR bean size::" +listCDRDetail.size());
      
        // Here I am passing of instance of that class.
        // And on each new request i am getting a new instance pjs.
        taskExecutor.runZcrJob(pjs, dbParam, listCDRDetail, type, txn);
        return listCDRDetail;
        
    }
```

Comment: By letting spring inject the properly configured `PriorityJobScheduler` and not using `new` yourself.

Comment: @luk2302 thanks for your reply .
could you please share an code example how can create a object of PriorityJobScheduler only once with constructor params and use it for all request?

Comment: public void scheduleJob(DowloadProccess job) { priorityQueue.add(job); log.debug("Jobs in queu :: " + priorityQueue.size()); } by calling the above above method i am adding a new job in priorityQueue so on each request size of priorityQueue much increse by one as i am addding new Job in each request. but the issue is on new request i get new priorityQuery with only one entry.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the bean in the Spring container

```
@Configuration
class JobSchedulerConfig {
    private static int POOL_SIZE = 1;
    private static int QUEUE_SIZE = 100;

    @Bean
    public PriorityJobScheduler createJobScheduler() {
         return new PriorityJobScheduler(POOL_SIZE, QUEUE_SIZE);
    }
}
```

And then Inject this bean in the Rest Controller.

```
@RestController
public class ZcrController {

   private final PriorityJobScheduler priorityJobScheduler;

   @Autowired // kept it for readability
   public ZcrController(PriorityJobScheduler priorityJobScheduler) {
      this.priorityJobScheduler = priorityJobScheduler;
   }

   ...
}
```

Comment: Note: It would be a good idea to make the `POOL_SIZE` and `QUEUE_SIZE` constants, configurable with properties, like `@Value("${scheduler.pool-size}") private String poolSize;` (the same for queue size)

Comment: I just tried this i am still gettting new instance on each request

Comment: public void scheduleJob(DowloadProccess job) {   
       priorityQueue.add(job);   
       log.debug("Jobs in queu :: " +  priorityQueue.size());   
   }   

by calling the above above method i am adding a new job in priorityQueue so on each request size of priorityQueue much increse by one as i am addding new Job in each request.

but the issue is on new request i get new priorityQuery with only one entry.

Comment: @RahulRai as soon as you add an object to the PriorityQueue , `while (true) {}` will remove it. Just for debugging, try replacing `take()` with `poll()`, you'll see the actual size.

Comment: using poll() method has same results i changed my approch for this perticular task(Problem)